# installing ubuntu and removing fedora

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

how to uninstall fedora 20 and install ubuntu from windows 7 dual boot keeping windows unchanged without windows installation CD?
please help its very urgent.

Comment: Just slide in the CD or USB Pen, and install Ubuntu over Fedora (alongisde of Windows of course).

Comment: @EliahKagan If you use the partitioner to remove the existing Fedora installation, then you can use the option to install Ubuntu alongside the Windows

Answer (score 0):

Use the CD or USB pen to boot the Ubuntu installation. With the partitioner erase the Fedora partitions, and join then in one big partition.

After that, use the installation menu that says Install Ubuntu alongside Windows, it should choose the partition you created.

Also, installing GRUB again will overwrite your existing Grub menu.